# Why is my keyword not being recognised by strpos()?

Tags: php, string, loops

I have this code and have run it through a validator - I can see no issues.

```
$verb = array("count","draw","Write");
echo $sentence."<br>";

foreach ($verb as $v)
{
    echo "Verb=" . $v;
    echo "<br>";

    $pos = strpos($sentence, $v);

    if ($pos === true) {
        echo "<br> Match found<br>";
        $check="1";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Not found!<br>";
        $check="0";
    }
}

echo $check;
```

When `$sentence="Write"` (or anything else that has one of the items from `$verb` in it) -it comes back as `false`... `$check` always equals to `0` and I never get a `true` return for `$pos`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please read [the manual](http://php.net/strpos) for what `strpos` does and returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will return false if not found or the offset of the string if found, from the manual...

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

So comparing `$pos` to be `true` will never work

```
if ($pos === true) {
```

You can change it to ..

```
if ($pos !== false) {
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because, `strpos` does not return `true`, it instead returns the position of the substring in the main string. So, you should write your `if` condition like this:

```
if ($pos !== false)
```

Check more details here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php